# ImageMagick: OSError: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.XX' not found

Tags: python, gcc, makefile, imagemagick, embedded-linux

I am working on an embedded linux system and try to get `python-wand` running...

But i am not able to install anything on this system so i included them in the lib folder of my application (this folder will be linked to the system).

Its not possible to update the glibc version of the system.

To test if its working i am using:

```
from ctypes import *
cdll.LoadLibrary('libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6')
```

This will throw:

> OSError: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by
>   ../libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.6)

So is it possible to build ImageMagick with a different glibc version packed ?

I am new to compiling but this should work if i can change glibc only for ImageMagick.

Is it possible if i compile ImageMagick with a older version of glibc ?
Is the compiled code affected by the gcc / glibc version ?

Comment: libc is kinda critical for ImageMagick + Wand. You can cross-compile ImageMagick as a static library for the embedded system, but Wand can only work with shared libraries, so you would be forced back to a missing `libc.so` error.

Comment: i understood that libc is needed for imagemagick also that wand will only work with shared library since its using the above code for importing libMagick - but isnt it possible to point to a different libc file than the normal libc path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got this running on my embedded system:

- Get same glibc/eglibc version on the cross compile system.
- Compile imagemagick with this glibc version.

Don't forget to install libpng for png support...

> **Note:**
>
> If you want to use imagemagick combined with ghostscript to convert
>   pdf -> images don't forget that ghostscript is licensed under AGPL and
>   you cannot use this in your product unless you are using the same license,  or buy the license....

Answer (score 0):

You may set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to your path (./lib) before starting python.

If it's a headless system you may write a shell script besides your python script to set the variable right before starting the python and then start python. Then use that script in your autostart code.

Comment: since changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH  affects the hole system i cant do this, needs to be only for imagemagick

Comment: @Fabian, Don't worry. The whole system isn't affected. Environment variables stay local to your shell session or process in which you have changed/set them.

Comment: nvm but i am not able to change this on runtime since this container is running in a chrooted system and i cant edit the system at all because i just able to pack a lib folder within my app package...

Comment: I see. Then, can't you just change the command line which executes your script? Like: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH='./lib' python myscript.py` ? This runs only this instance of python with the custom set variable.

Comment: i dont use any command line i am using imagemagick combined with python-wand perhaps its possible to do `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.getcwd()`

Comment: I don't think so. Because Python loads libraries beforehand. But try your luck and report back.